# Passing Listview OnClick to Fetch Data from DB

Tags: sqlite, listview

I have a ListView which displays static data along with images (say Activity A). When I click a ListVoew Item, the data is captured and passed onto next Activity (lets call it Activity B). In Activity B, I want to pass the selected value into DB select where clause and fetch data and show relevant information pertaining to the selection. Here is my code snippet...

**Activity A**:

```
String subproduct = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_label)).getText().toString();
                      // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item

                      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("pref",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                      editor.clear();
                      editor.putString("subproduct", subproduct);
                      editor.commit();
                      Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Details.class);                 
                      startActivity(myIntent);
```

And here is my **Activity B**:`enter code here`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.details1);

SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_WORLD_READABLE); 
String subproduct = myPrefs.getString("subproduct","null");     
TextView txtProduct1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_item);
txtProduct1.setText(subproduct);
```

and here is my **DBHelper.java**. Here I want to pass the selected value. Please help me how I can acheive this...

```
public Cursor getData(){
        //SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("pref", 0);
        //String subproduct = myPrefs.getString("subproduct","null");
        Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Destmain WHERE destname= " + ? + " ", null);
        while (c.moveToNext()){
            DestInfo q = new DestInfo();
            q.setDestination(c.getString(1));
            q.setCity(c.getString(2));
            q.setCountry(c.getString(3));
            q.setPeriod(c.getString(4));
            q.setType(c.getString(5));
            q.setCurrency(c.getString(6));
            q.setBriefhistory(c.getString(7));
            q.setHighlights(c.getString(8));


        }
        c.close();
        return c;
```

Can anyone help me how I can pass the ListView (Activity A) selected value into fetching DB data and show in Activity B? Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

By using method `onItemcClick` in Activity A you can get the Id and pass it to the second Activity B.

```
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long id)
newActivity.putExtra("key", id);
```

then in Activity B you can use this Id to search on the Database.

```
Intent newActivity = getIntent();
long id = newActivity.getLongExtras("key", -1);
```

in some other case you can use `getLunchDetails` method